# Panels and checkboxes won't show up

Tags: java, swing

I am following along in my textbook trying to learn how to create a windowed application and using layout managers in Java. I have entered the code using textpad just like how the book shows however not everything shows up in my application. The application is a program to book a party room. It displays 8 panels for booking smoking and non smoking rooms. Has a choice list for number of guests, two check boxes for smoking and non smoking, 2 text fields for name and phone number and one button for booking the room. I have entered the code how it is shown in the book the only thing that shows is the 2 text field, choice list and the book room button. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. There are no compile errors.
Here is my external class named Rooms:

```
 public class Rooms{

//declaring variables
int numSmoking;
int numNonSmoking;
boolean occupied[];

//method for rooms
public Rooms(int non, int sm){
  occupied = new boolean[sm+non];

    //for loop for array occupied
    for(int i=0; i < (sm+non); i++)
        occupied[i] = false; //set each occupied room to false or empty
        //initialize the number of smoking and non smoking rooms
        numSmoking = sm;
        numNonSmoking = non;

}//end method rooms
//method to book room
public int bookRoom(boolean smoking){
    int begin, end;
    int roomNumber=0;

    //if statement for non smoking and smoking room booking
    if(!smoking){
        begin = 0;
        end = numNonSmoking;
    }//end if
    else{
        begin = numNonSmoking;
        end = numSmoking+numNonSmoking;
    }//end else
    for (int i=begin; i < end; i++){
        if(!occupied[i]){//if room not occupied
        occupied[i] = true;
        roomNumber = i+1;
        i = end;//to exit loop
    }//end if
}//end for
return roomNumber;

 }//end method bookroom

}//ends class
```

Here is my main class I named Module5example2:

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.Color;

 public class Module5example2 extends Frame implements  
  ActionListener{//
//creating color
Color lightRed = new Color(255, 90, 90);
Color lightGreen = new Color(140, 215, 40);

//variables
Rooms room = new Rooms(5, 3);

Panel roomPanel = new Panel();
    TextArea roomDisplay[] = new TextArea[9];

Panel buttonPanel = new Panel();
    Button bookButton = new Button("Book Room");

Panel inputPanel = new Panel();
    Label custNameLabel = new Label("Name");
    TextField nameField = new TextField(15);
    Label custPhoneLabel = new Label("Phone Number");
    TextField phoneField = new TextField(15);
    Label numLabel = new Label("Number in Party");
    Choice numberOfGuests = new Choice();
    CheckboxGroup options = new CheckboxGroup();
        Checkbox nonSmoking = new Checkbox("Nonsmoking",false,options);
        Checkbox smoking = new Checkbox("Smoking",false,options);
        Checkbox hidden = new Checkbox("",true,options);

//reservation method
public  Module5example2(){// (B Reserv)  constructor method
//set layouts for frame and three panels
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        roomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4,10,10));
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        inputPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //add components to room panel
    for (int i=1; i<9; i++){ //(C for)
        roomDisplay[i] = new TextArea(null,3,5,3);
        if(i<6){
            roomDisplay[i].setText("Room " + i + " Nonsmoking");
        }
        else{
            roomDisplay[i].setText("Room " + i + " Smoking");
        roomDisplay[i].setEditable(false);
        roomDisplay[i].setBackground(lightGreen);
        roomPanel.add(roomDisplay[i]);
        }//end else
    }//(C for closed)end for loop

//add components to button panel
buttonPanel.add(bookButton);

//add components to input label
inputPanel.add(custNameLabel);
inputPanel.add(nameField);
inputPanel.add(custPhoneLabel);
inputPanel.add(phoneField);
inputPanel.add(numLabel);
inputPanel.add(numberOfGuests);

for (int i = 8; i <= 20; i++)
    numberOfGuests.add(String.valueOf(i));
inputPanel.add(nonSmoking);
inputPanel.add(smoking);

//add panels to frame
add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

bookButton.addActionListener(this);

//overriding the windowClosing() method will alow the user to click
//the close button

addWindowListener(
    new WindowAdapter(){//
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){//
            System.exit(0);
        }//close window closing method
    }// close window adapter
 );
}//(end constructor method 

//main
public static void main(String[] args){
Module5example2 f = new Module5example2();
f.setBounds(200,200,600,300);
f.setTitle("Reserve a Party Room");
f.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
 if(hidden.getState()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," You must select Nonsmoking or   
    Smoking.",
    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
else{
        int available = room.bookRoom(smoking.getState());
        if (available > 0){//(end 2nd if)
            roomDisplay[available].setBackground(lightRed);
            roomDisplay[available].setText(

            roomDisplay[available].getText()+
                                            "\n" +
                                            nameField.getText() +
                                            " " +
                                            phoneField.getText() +
                                            "\nparty of" +
                                         numberOfGuests.getSelectedItem()

                                             );
        clearFields();
        }

        else{ //room is not available
                 if (smoking.getState())
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Smoking is full.","Error",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


                 else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nonsmoking is full.",  
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    hidden.setState(true);


    }
  }
}

 //reset the text field choice components
void clearFields(){
nameField.setText("");
phoneField.setText("");
numberOfGuests.select(0);
nameField.requestFocus();
hidden.setState(true);
}//end void clearfield


}//(A Class closed)end class rexervations
```

Comment: How old is your textbook?  This code uses `Frame`, `Panel` and so on, which are part of the AWT and have been superceded a long time ago by `JFrame`, `JPanel`, etc, which are part of Swing.

Comment: Is that why its not working? in my book it didnt have the import java.awt.Color I had to input that just to get the colors. I am using text pad 7 and the latest Java sdk and JRE. I am using Java Programming: Comprehensive Concepts and Techniques 3rd edition. copyrighted in 2006. It doesn't mention anything about JFrame or JPanel. What is the best book to learn about that?

Comment: No, the code is consistent in its use of AWT so that's not a problem; mixing Swing and AWT components can cause problems though.

Comment: oh ok. I'm just trying my best to understand how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add roomPanel to the JFrame. You need to add the panel to JFrame to get it displayed. 
Just creating a JPanel instance and setting the properties wont help.

So your code needs to be modified as :

```
//add panels to frame
add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(roomPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER); //<----- You missed this.
```

**EDIT:**
I am just suggesting how to show panels on JFrames content pane. When you copy or read and type stuff from book/internet, please make sure you understand what/why each line is provided.
Again, you see only 3 green boxes because there is a bug in your for loop to add room boxes to the panel. Because of

```
if(i<6){
  roomDisplay[i].setText("Room " + i + " Nonsmoking");
}
```

You are skipping addition of first 6 boxes to the panel. I am not sure if that is a "business" requirement so I can not comment further.

Comment: Now it shows only 3 room panels smoking rooms 6 through 8. At least i'm getting somewhere now...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will fix it.